# If else shorthand inside array .push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, push, array-push

Why I can do `if else shorthand` inside `.push()` function ? like

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(test||null);
// nothing
```

But

```
var arr = [];
var test = test||null;
arr.push(test);
// [null]
```

I need to insert `null` if variable is undefined.

Why I cant use `test||null` inside `.push()` function ?

Comment: Your first example causes an error, that's why nothing happens. Please take a look at the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use

```
arr.push(test||null);
```

if you define test. Why your second code is working ?

```
var arr = [];
var test = test||null;
arr.push(test);
// [null]
```

It's working because you have defined test.

So, this works

```
var test;
var arr = [];
arr.push(test||null);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
arr.push(typeof(test) == "undefined" ? null: test);
```

Comment: Thanks , Ahhhh I looking longer version, But work :P

Comment: You're code will work if you define test, like @MC ND says in his answer.

Comment: this is a late reply but `typeof` works even the variable is not declared.